# POST 400 error, ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Why cant I save this, I get 400 (Bad Request), 
and on headers response i get The CSRF token could not be verified.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

            $("a#copylink").click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var data = $('#campaign-form').serialize();

                $.ajax(
                    {
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: 'json',
                        method: 'POST',
                        url: 'campaignsave',
                        data: data,
                        success: function(data){
                            alert(data);
                        }
                    }
                )
                    });
            });
```

on backend:

```
public function actionCampaignSave()
    {
        var_dump($_POST);

    }
```

Comment: Where is your CSRF token being passed?

Comment: shows in Request Payload csrf_token=1b7c4749ebc8e6b0a8cb47f17ba902c9f7bf3976&Campaign%5Bname%5D=

Comment: is that where it is supposed to be? how do i pass it to the header

Comment: i added  headers : {
                            'X-CSRF-TOKEN' : $('meta[name=csrf-token-name]').attr('content')
                        },      but still get same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass csrf token using headers property on ajax

```
$.ajax({
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: 'json',
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'campaignsave',
  headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': 'token' }
  data: data,
  success: function(data){
      alert(data);
  }
});
```

Comment: is it where it is supposed to go?

Comment: Add 'X-CSRF-TOKEN' header to headers object. For example
headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': your token here }

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the [headers] parameter in your ajax call like this.

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'campaignsave',
    method : 'POST',,
    headers : {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN' : $('input[name="token"]').val()
    }
    dataType : 'json',
    data : data,
    success : function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

Just make sure you've place {!! csrf_field() !!} on your [view] blade template to append the $(input[name="token"); html tag to get the token value to get the CSRF token as well. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Try this it may help you

```
 $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: 'campaignsave',
                    data: {test : data},
                    success: function(data) {
                         alert(data);
                    }
                });
```